# Namespaces in JavaScript: do I need to rewrite all my variable and function references?

Tags: javascript

I am namespacing some JavaScript code, and I want to know if I have rewritten all my function calls and references to global variables correctly. The current code is this:

```
var x = 10;
function foo() {
    console.log('foo');
    bar();
  },
function bar() {
  console.log('bar', x);
}  
foo();
```

I have rewritten it as follows:

```
var namespace = {  
  x : 10,
  foo: function() {
    console.log('foo');
    // Is this the correct way to call bar?
    this.bar();
  },
  bar: function() {
    // Is this the correct way to refer to x?  
    console.log('bar', this.x);
  }  
};
namespace.foo();
```

Is this correct, i.e. do I need to rewrite all function calls (EDIT: by which I mean all inside the namespace variable) to `this.functionname()` and all global variables to `this.variablename`?

Answer (score 0):

No, in some places (code that calls those functions from outside of your namespace object) you would have to call `namespace.foo()`, `namespace.bar()`, `namespace.varName`

Actually, if you use `namespace.bar()` from the function in the object itself, you get the added benefit that your functions don't depend on context. That is, the following code doesn't work with what you have

```
var fun = namespace.foo;
fun(); // This would break, since the this value is going to be the global object
```

I usually don't like to use `this` from literal objects because of the problem mentioned above. It's definitely a preference, I just prefer to avoid problems with `this`

Answer (score 0):

If you like, you can make yourself some "real" private variables and methods by incorporating a closure. I favour the module pattern.

```
var ns = (function () {  
  var x = 10;
    return {
        foo: function () {
            console.log('foo');
            this.bar();
        },
        bar: function () {
            console.log('bar', x);
        },
        increment: function () {
            x++;   
        }
    }
}());

ns.foo();
ns.increment();
ns.foo();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/DjYue/

Answer (score 0):

No, you shouldn't rewrite to `this.funcname()` but rather `namespace.funcname()`. The `this` keyword is reserved to refer to the current context object (or whatever it's called), meaning that you'd use it within your "namespaced" code to refer to the namespace object.

And generally, it's good to know that you aren't actually working with namespaces as you'd know it from more classical OOP. JavaScript is a prototype-based language, which means that you *don't* have namespaces - rather, what you're creating is an object containing several properties and methods. As previously mentioned, when you're working with methods of the object, the `this` keyword refers to the object itself. You'd need a reference to the object when outside of it's context.

Currently, the approach of using objects to contain all of your code as a sort of namespaces and classes in disguise is diminishing in favor of closures which attaches the methods and properties that should be publicly available to a function (which, in JavaScript, is a first class object), and either returns that function or attaches it to the global object. You may also, alternatively, use a function to contain the properties and methods instead of an object.

Comment: Thanks - what about variables, should they also be declared as e.g. `namespace.x : 10`, or not?

Comment: If you refer to them from the outside of the `namespace` object, yes. But with an equals-sign instead of a colon as the assignment operator. When declaring inside the object code, you'd simply use `x : 10`.

Comment: What if you refer to them inside the namespace object - `this.x` or `namespace.x`?

Comment: It depends (both are valid because JavaScript is not a strongly typed language, buth have their respective use cases). If `namespace` is an object that is not copied or instanciated in any way at any time, you *could* use `namespace.x` inside the code for it to refer to itself. If you're creating instances of the object/function however, you'd use `this.x`, which would then refer to the object instance. I personally prefer to use `this` in any case, as it's usually shorter than the name of the object, thus making cleaner and less verbose code. We don't want JavaScript to look like Java.

Answer (score 0):

I disagree with the people who say No to your question. It really depends on what you want to accomplish here. Based the rewritten code, I don't see anything wrong with it. As long as you call `namespace.foo()`, the execution context of each function should be `namespace`. Thus, it is not wrong to use `this`.

There is a situation that invoking the function foo() will not work:

```
var foo1 = namespace.foo;
foo1();
```

Although `foo1` is same as the function `namespace.foo`, `foo1`'s execution context has changed. `this` will refer to `window`, not `namespace`.

Answer (score 0):

Their is no need to rewrite that much because you can have more than one reference to a function - a private and a public one.

```
var namespace = (function() {
    var ns = {}; // the 'namespace'
    var x = 10;

    var foo = // 'private' reference: bar();
    ns.foo =  // 'public'  reference: ns.bar() -> namespace.bar();
    function foo() { // the name is optional because it's a function expression
        console.log('foo');
        bar();
    }; // don't forget the semicolon

    var bar =
    ns.bar =
    function() {
        console.log('bar', x);
    };

    return ns; // return the 'namespace'
})();

namespace.foo();

var foo = namespace.foo;
foo();
delete namespace.bar;
// namespace.bar(); // Error
foo(); // bar is called
```